# Log-in system errors

Tags: php, mysql

As weird as this sounds for my Database Management Class I have to write a log-in system that stores the user's password for 90 days so that all they have to do is put in their username to login. Yes I know this is extremely insecure and don't see it ever being practical but its what the teacher wants. I have everything working except evaluating whether or not the time is past 90 days.

This is the code I currently have to check and see if it is past 90 days. the 'Time' member of the MySql database is a INT and I have a feeling that the error is in the comparison between `$member['Time'] <= time()`

```
//create query
    $qry="SELECT * FROM MEMBER WHERE username='$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result=mysql_query($qry);
    $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    //Input Validations
    if($username == '') {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Username missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
    if($password == '' && $member['Time'] <= time()) {
        $errmsg_arr[] = 'Password missing';
        $errflag = true;
    }
     else
     {
        $qry="SELECT * FROM MEMBER WHERE username='$username'";
        $result=mysql_query($qry);
     }
```

This is where I insert the current time into the database + 90 days to store the time at which the password will be required.

```
 $days = 90*24*60*60;
        $ttl = time() + $days;

                if($member['Time'] <= time() || $member['Time'] === NULL)
                {
                    $query = "UPDATE MEMBER set Time='$ttl' WHERE username = '$username'";
                    $result = mysql_query($query);
                    if(!$result)
                    {
                        die("Query Failed");
                    }
                }
```

Yes. I know I'm using deprecated functions, but this is what my teacher has taught us to use.

Comment: The teacher has to be `deprecated` ;)

Comment: Now there's a first-timer @ShankarDamodaran – the `teacher` eh?

Comment: This `if($password == '' && $member['Time'] <= time()) {` should probably be `if($password == '' && $member['Time'] <= $ttl) {` just a hunch, since `time()` has already been defined in `$ttl`

Comment: @Fred-ii-at that point I'm attempting to see whether I need to update the time before the password becomes invalid. Wouldn't comparing it to $ttl constantly update it everytime?

Comment: @todaroa as I said, it was ***just a hunch*** in thinking that, if the time difference was less or equal to what has been defined in `$ttl`